# How to write my rewriterule so I can have friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, seo, url-rewriting, opencart, friendly-url

My SEO expert asked me to do HTTP 301 redirect to a friendly URL in an Opencart installation. This Opencart installation use SEO url so I have this url (native url in opencart) : 
http://www.qcbikeshop.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=9

and the SEO url is :
http://www.qcbikeshop.com/Livraison-Gratuite

However, my SEO expert want me to do a HTTP 301 redirect so that when someone access the native URL (the first one), he his redirected to the SEO url.

When I try to do it in .htaccess, Apache say it is in an endless loop and I understand it. But I didn't found how to achieve what I'm trying to do.

Here's my current rewrite stuff in my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qcbikeshop\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.qcbikeshop\.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/qcbikeshop\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qcbike\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.qcbike\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/qcbikeshop\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qcbike\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.qcbike\.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/qcbikeshop\.com" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^spherikbike\.ca$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.spherikbike\.ca$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.spherikbike\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Redirect 301 /mtb-comp-fr.html http://www.qcbikeshop.com/accessoires/pompes-velo/mtb-comp-fr.html
```

CPanel Rewrite tool generate this for my example above :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^qcbikeshop\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.qcbikeshop\.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ "http\:\/\/www\.qcbikeshop\.com\/Livraison\-Gratuite" [R=301,L]
```

It seems very wrong to me. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: what are your current rules?

Comment: Post edited and current rules added! Thanks for your interest!

Comment: The problem I see is how does it map the native URL to the new SEO? Meaning there is nothing from the native URL that is used in the SEO friendly rule, So I don't see how you will be able to make a dynamic rule. It appears you'd have to make a rule for each redirect from Native to SEO.

Comment: I think Opencart do the mapping of the native url to the new SEO one. I have updated my post with what CPanel Redirect generate in the .htaccess file for what I tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place this rule above the others and see how it works for you.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?information/information&information=9
RewriteRule .* /Livraison-Gratuite? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks it works great! I'll do some search to understand your solution so I can apply this to other url I have to do 301 redirect.

Comment: No problem glad it worked out. It should be similar for your other URL's. Just replace the query string parts on RewriteCond and then SEO part in the RewriteRule

Comment: ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ this is regex? May I ask you what is it for?

Comment: It just basically says it can match uppercase letters from A-Z and can be between 3 and 9 letters. It's so it can match the type of request that's in THE_REQUEST variable. e.g. GET or HEAD etc.